# Open and bring new window to front when pressing NSMenuItem

Tags: macos, nsmenu

I have a macOS menu application that is running as an agent (LSUIElement).

I need it to have a companion settings window. There is a "settings" NSMenuItem in the NSMenu, and the requirement is to open an actual window and bring it to the front when pressed.

The window is SwiftUI driven. Here's how it's working:

```
// main is an NSMenu
        main.addItem(
            withTitle: "Settings",
            action: #selector(AppDelegate.openSettings),
            keyEquivalent: "")
```

```
    @objc func openSettings() {
        let detailView = SettingsWindow(); // Swift UI view
        let controller = DetailWindowController(rootView: detailView) // See below
        controller.window?.title = "Settings";
        controller.showWindow(nil)
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    }
```

```
class DetailWindowController<RootView : View>: NSWindowController {
    convenience init(rootView: RootView) {
        let hostingController = NSHostingController(rootView: rootView.frame(width: 400, height: 500))
        let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: hostingController)
        window.setContentSize(NSSize(width: 400, height: 500))
        self.init(window: window)
    }
}
```

### What actually happens

The current behaviour is that the window opens, however it's always behind whatever other windows are currently in the foreground.

I need it to be in the foreground.

`NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)` in the code above is an attempt to achieve this, but that didn't work.

Any help would be amazing. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in the end. I needed these 3. The activation policy should be better managed, but for what it's worth here's what works.

```
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
settingsWindow!.window?.orderFrontRegardless()
```

In context

```
@objc func openSettings() {
    if(settingsWindow == nil) {
        let detailView = ActionWindow();
        settingsWindow = DetailWindowController(rootView: detailView)
        settingsWindow!.window?.title = "Cloud Brains - Settings";
        settingsWindow!.showWindow(nil)
    }
    NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    settingsWindow!.window?.orderFrontRegardless()
}
```